# Connecting Aurdiuno ESP-01 wifi with led matrix MAX7219

Tags: arduino-esp8266

01 has only 2 giop's and a tx,rx. How can I connect esp-01 to led matrix max7318 so that I can remotely display content.

Comment: use 3 io: io0, io 1 (rx), io 2.  and on tx you can have debug prints

Comment: Do you have any circuit connection and codes

Comment: only what google found. you need software SPI. use rx as MOSI, io 0 and io 2, try which works better as CLK and which as CS. https://www.gammon.com.au/images/BL-M12A881_e.png